# Display activity indicator inside UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I would like to change the content of a UIButton to an ActivityIndicator after it is pressed.

I know buttons have an imageView and a titleLabel, but I don't know how to put an activity indicator in any of them.

This is how I create activity indicators:

```
let aiView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
aiView.startAnimating()
aiView.center = CGPointMake(0,0)
aiView.hidesWhenStopped = false
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class LoadingButton: UIButton {
private var originalButtonText: String?
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

func showLoading() {
    originalButtonText = self.titleLabel?.text
    self.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    
    if (activityIndicator == nil) {
        activityIndicator = createActivityIndicator()
    }
    
    showSpinning()
}

func hideLoading() {
    self.setTitle(originalButtonText, for: .normal)
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}

private func createActivityIndicator() -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.color = .lightGray
    return activityIndicator
}

private func showSpinning() {
    activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    centerActivityIndicatorInButton()
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

private func centerActivityIndicatorInButton() {
    let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(xCenterConstraint)
    
    let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(yCenterConstraint)
}
}
```

Comment: For basic use that looks great. +1

Comment: Remember to update the class of your button in storyboard to the custom class. E.g. Identity Inspector > Custom Class = LoadingButton. Otherwise you'll get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: if your using IB, use NSAttributedString. Because IB sets the attibutedString. self.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: ""), for: .normal)

Comment: I suggest add: `activityIndicator.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`  .... otherwise touches on the activityIndicator won't execute the button's target.

Comment: since iOS 15, you can use `button.configuration?.showsActivityIndicator = true`

Answer (score 29):

@Boris: This should not be in an extension.

Here it is in swift 3/4, with improved code: disables button, works with images and titles.

```
class LoadingButton: UIButton {

    struct ButtonState {
        var state: UIControlState
        var title: String?
        var image: UIImage?
    }

    private (set) var buttonStates: [ButtonState] = []
    private lazy var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.color = self.titleColor(for: .normal)
        self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.addConstraints([xCenterConstraint, yCenterConstraint])
        return activityIndicator
    }()

    func showLoading() {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        var buttonStates: [ButtonState] = []
        for state in [UIControlState.disabled] {
            let buttonState = ButtonState(state: state, title: title(for: state), image: image(for: state))
            buttonStates.append(buttonState)
            setTitle("", for: state)
            setImage(UIImage(), for: state)
        }
        self.buttonStates = buttonStates
        isEnabled = false
    }

    func hideLoading() {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        for buttonState in buttonStates {
            setTitle(buttonState.title, for: buttonState.state)
            setImage(buttonState.image, for: buttonState.state)
        }
        isEnabled = true
    }

}
```

Comment: fyi, if you have a button in the storyboard you'd have to change its type inside the identity inspector not just in code.

Comment: How do I use this LoadingButton, do I need to set the State, Title and Image on initialisation ? An example on its usage would be great.

Answer (score 18):

Swift 4.0 with a little modification

```
class LoadingUIButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var indicatorColor : UIColor = .lightGray

    var originalButtonText: String?
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    func showLoading() {
        originalButtonText = self.titleLabel?.text
        self.setTitle("", for: .normal)

        if (activityIndicator == nil) {
            activityIndicator = createActivityIndicator()
        }

        showSpinning()
    }

    func hideLoading() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.setTitle(self.originalButtonText, for: .normal)
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        })
    }

    private func createActivityIndicator() -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.color = indicatorColor
        return activityIndicator
    }

    private func showSpinning() {
        activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        centerActivityIndicatorInButton()
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    private func centerActivityIndicatorInButton() {
        let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.addConstraint(xCenterConstraint)

        let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.addConstraint(yCenterConstraint)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13):

Swift 4:

```
extension UIButton {
    func loadingIndicator(_ show: Bool) {
        let tag = 808404
        if show {
            self.isEnabled = false
            self.alpha = 0.5
            let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
            let buttonHeight = self.bounds.size.height
            let buttonWidth = self.bounds.size.width
            indicator.center = CGPoint(x: buttonWidth/2, y: buttonHeight/2)
            indicator.tag = tag
            self.addSubview(indicator)
            indicator.startAnimating()
        } else {
            self.isEnabled = true
            self.alpha = 1.0
            if let indicator = self.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIActivityIndicatorView {
                indicator.stopAnimating()
                indicator.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**: `button.loadingIndicator(true/false)`

Answer (score 9):

i have written a library in **swift**, it has **7 different styles and animations to show an indicatorview in uibutton**, here it is

**https://github.com/farshadjahanmanesh/loady**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5, Xcode 11.3

I've modified it for my use case to include the button text, together with the spinner

```
import UIKit

class LoadingButton: UIButton {

var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

let activityIndicatorColor: UIColor = .gray

func loadIndicator(_ shouldShow: Bool) {
    if shouldShow {
        if (activityIndicator == nil) {
            activityIndicator = createActivityIndicator()
        }
        self.isEnabled = false
        self.alpha = 0.7
        showSpinning()
    } else {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.isEnabled = true
        self.alpha = 1.0
    }
}

private func createActivityIndicator() -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.color = activityIndicatorColor
    return activityIndicator
}

private func showSpinning() {
    activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    positionActivityIndicatorInButton()
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

private func positionActivityIndicatorInButton() {
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                                               attribute: .trailing,
                                               relatedBy: .equal,
                                               toItem: activityIndicator,
                                               attribute: .trailing,
                                               multiplier: 1, constant: 16)
    self.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)

    let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                                               attribute: .centerY,
                                               relatedBy: .equal,
                                               toItem: activityIndicator,
                                               attribute: .centerY,
                                               multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(yCenterConstraint)
}

}
```

If you're using storyboard, ensure that your button is of type LoadingButton (do this on your storyboard as well as view controller file, otherwise it'll crash)

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: LoadingButton!
```

and to use it,

```
myButton.loadIndicator(true)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Here is my edit with little less code.

```
class Button: UIButton {
    private var originalButtonText: String?

    private lazy var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        activityIndicator.color = .black
        addSubview(activityIndicator)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor)
        ])

        return activityIndicator
    }()

    func loading(_ isLoading: Bool) {
        isEnabled = !isLoading

        if isLoading {
            originalButtonText = titleLabel?.text
            setTitle("", for: .normal)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        } else {
            setTitle(originalButtonText, for: .normal)
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `button.loading(true/false)`

Comment: This solution breaks now

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for Swift4, I tried to make it simpler than previous solutions. This Extension allows you to resize the UIActivityIndicatorView (scale) to make fit inside the UIButton, and change the color.

[https://gist.github.com/jalopezsuarez/0ecc885b3fd5c555630799a067d66d98](https://gist.github.com/jalopezsuarez/0ecc885b3fd5c555630799a067d66d98.js)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class UIButtonActivity: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var indicatorColor : UIColor = .lightGray

    private var buttonLabel: String?

    func startAnimating() {
        self.isEnabled = false

        buttonLabel = self.titleLabel?.text
        self.setTitle("", for: .normal)

        let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        indicator.color = indicatorColor
        indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

        let buttonHeight = self.bounds.size.height
        let buttonWidth = self.bounds.size.width
        indicator.center = CGPoint(x: buttonWidth/2, y: buttonHeight/2)

        let scale = max(min((self.frame.size.height - 4) / 21, 2.0), 0.0)
        let transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        indicator.transform = transform

        self.addSubview(indicator)
        indicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func stopAnimating() {
        self.isEnabled = true

        if let titleLabel = buttonLabel {
            self.setTitle(titleLabel, for: .normal)
        }

        if let indicator = self.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIActivityIndicatorView {
            indicator.stopAnimating()
            indicator.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, but in stop animating you have viewWithTag, without a tag really being assigned. It might work for you but I had to manually assign a tag to the indicatorview for it to work. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Updated selected answer( steve-rosenberg ) for Apple Swift version 3.0.1 (swiftlang-800.0.58.6 clang-800.0.42.1) Xcode 8.1 (8B62)

```
import ObjectiveC

private var originalButtonText: String?
private var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

extension UIButton{

    func showLoading() {
        originalButtonText = self.titleLabel?.text
        self.setTitle("", for: .normal)

        if (activityIndicator == nil) {
            activityIndicator = createActivityIndicator()
        }

        showSpinning()
    }

    func hideLoading() {
        self.setTitle(originalButtonText, for: .normal)
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    private func createActivityIndicator() -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor.lightGray
        return activityIndicator
    }

    func showSpinning() {
        activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        centerActivityIndicatorInButton()
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    private func centerActivityIndicatorInButton() {
        let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.addConstraint(xCenterConstraint)

        let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.addConstraint(yCenterConstraint)
    }
}
```

Comment: originalButtonText is global variable, what if we need to show loader on multiple buttons?

Comment: @NishuPriya this is a UIButton extension so you may use it for each of your buttons independently

Answer (score 1):

Excellent @Steve,

Can use below implementation instead of line,

var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

use this, so that if we configure the activity indicator before calling showLoading(), the app wont crash.

```
private var _activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView! = nil
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView{
    set{
        _activityIndicator = newValue

    }
    get{
        if _activityIndicator == nil{
            _activityIndicator = createActivityIndicator()
        }
        return _activityIndicator
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers are working with only title, in my case I need to manage attributed text and image as well,

```
import UIKit

class LoadingButton: UIButton {

    struct ButtonState {
        var state: UIControl.State
        var title: String?
        var attributedTitle: NSAttributedString?
        var image: UIImage?
    }

    private (set) var buttonStates: [ButtonState] = []

    private lazy var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.color = self.titleColor(for: .normal)
        self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: activityIndicator, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.addConstraints([xCenterConstraint, yCenterConstraint])
        return activityIndicator
    }()

    func showLoading() {
        activityIndicator.color = self.titleColor(for: .normal)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        var buttonStates: [ButtonState] = []
        for state in [UIControl.State.disabled] {
            let buttonState = ButtonState(state: state, title: title(for: state), attributedTitle: attributedTitle(for: state), image: image(for: state))
        buttonStates.append(buttonState)
            setTitle("", for: state)
            setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: ""), for: state)
            setImage(UIImage(), for: state)
        }
        self.buttonStates = buttonStates
        isEnabled = false
   }

   func hideLoading() {
       activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
       for buttonState in buttonStates {
           setTitle(buttonState.title, for: buttonState.state)
           setImage(buttonState.image, for: buttonState.state)
           setAttributedTitle(buttonState.attributedTitle, for: buttonState.state)
       }
       isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If someone looking for Swift UI code [SWIFT 5]**

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonContentView: View {
    @State private var isButtonPressed = false
    @State private var isLoading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    isButtonPressed.toggle()
                    isLoading.toggle()
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    withAnimation {
                        isButtonPressed.toggle()
                        isLoading.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }) {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    Text(isButtonPressed ? "" : "Press Me")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: isButtonPressed ? 60 : 200, height: isButtonPressed ? 60 : 50)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .clipShape(isButtonPressed ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50) : RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                }
                
            }
            
            if isLoading {
                CircularProgressView()
                    .opacity(isButtonPressed ? 1 : 0)
                    .scaleEffect(isButtonPressed ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CircularProgressView: View {
    @State private var rotation = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.08, to: 1.0)
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotation))
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)
                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                            rotation = 360.0
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ButtonContentView_previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ButtonContentView()
    }
}
```