# How to set indicatorType during setBackgroundImage for UIButton using Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

In Kingfisher documentation there is information about setting indicatorType when set image for regular imageView:

```
    imageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
    imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

But how to set indicatorType when set background image for UIButton?

```
    myButton.kf.setBackgroundImage(with: url, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No direct way to do that

but you can do it like that create Custom `UIButton` with indicator
like that

[Display activity indicator inside UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539650/display-activity-indicator-inside-uibutton)

Then use like this

```
let btn = LoadingButton()
    btn.showLoading()
    btn.kf.setBackgroundImage(with: URL(string: ""), for: .normal) { (image, error, cachType, url) in
      btn.hideLoading()
    }
```